# AngularJS Set Value to $scope from Nested Function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope, closures

I'm trying to get a value from a function inside a function:

**Controller**

```
  $scope.vm = {};

  function myFunc(){
    $scope.vm.hello = 'Hello';
    function myFunction(){
      $scope.vm.world = 'world';
    }
  }

  myFunc();
```

**View**

```
<p>{{vm.hello}} {{vm.world}}</p>
```

[Here's my Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/vfjZR80UOAtcoumtZNUP?p=preview).

How can I get this to display "Hello world"?

Comment: the inner `myFunction()` is never called?

Comment: You need to call `myFunction()` as well right?, and that too from within `myFunc` since it wont be accessible outside. Just the way you are invoking `myFunc();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are trying to achieve something called 'closure'. If so, modify your controller to:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.vm = {};

  function myFunc(){
    $scope.vm.hello = 'Hello';
    return function () {
      $scope.vm.world = 'world';
    }
  }

  var hello = myFunc(), // invokes outer function
      world = hello();  // invokes inner function

  console.log($scope.vm);      
});
```

In your code, the inner function `myFunction()` cannot be called outside the `myFunc()` method, because its scope is bounded by this outer method. You can of course call it directly inside outer method, or better - make the inner function immediate:

```
  function myFunc(){
    $scope.vm.hello = 'Hello';
    (function myFunction(){
      $scope.vm.world = 'world';
    })();
  }
```